Problem with submitting nextjs application to github
enter image description hereWhy is this process (Compressing objects, Writing and Receiving) taking so long. What am I doing wrong and how can I make it go away?
Added node_modules and .next to the .gitignore folder
I tried deleting and recreating the repository, deleting the .next folder, adding it to gitignore. Has anyone fixed this bug?

What do you mean with „taking so long“?
